# Handle "left" or error cases of Option and Result without a closure

Tags: rust

A very frequent pattern I see in Rust is:

```
let a = match some_option {
    Some(a) => a,
    None => { return or continue or break or some control flow },
};
```

and the same for `Result`

```
let a = match some_result {
    Ok(a) => a,
    Err(e) => { return or continue or break or some control flow },
};
```

The `?` operator is nice, but returning an error isn't always the desired behaviour, and for those cases, the value case is commonly extracted without modification.

Is there a nice way to do this? `try` blocks seem like they might help, but they're not stable yet, and I'm not sure about how well they apply to this common case. There's also `let-else` expressions, but they don't give you access to the `Err` contents for the `else` clause.

When I first started Rust I created a macro for this, but that might have been overkill. Is there a convention I'm missing?

Comment: "There's also let-else expressions, but they don't give you access to the Err contents for the else clause." in 100% of the Option cases and 95% of the Result cases you don't need the error value if you're bailing, and when you do you can usually `map_err` to store it somewhere (eventually [`inspect_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err)). In the ~0.1% where you need to bail, need to process the error type, and it doesn't really fit in a `map_err` you can just use a full `match` it's not like it stops working.

Comment: It might be useful to make the question more speicfic. I'm sure we could come up with some recommendations for specific use cases. I at least don't frequently encounter the need for the constructs you mentioned.

Comment: Also note that you can access the error payload in the `else` branch of `let-else` with `some_result.unwrap_err()`.

Comment: I think the idiomatic way to do this is precisely `match`.  I've noticed that lately there is this view that writing a `match` is like admitting defeat, but IMO it is a perfectly fine thing to write. It is not as if you were doing an unnecessary clone...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a macro is probably the most concise that you're going to get.

Not that it's a "bad" solution - simple macros like that should not have too much cognitive load, especially if named properly.

For some cases that involve returning, [the try trait RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3058-try-trait-v2.html) may help solve some of that by letting you implement your own behavior for `?` with custom types, but it's not stable yet.